# Trying to understand the order of the legend labels when using pandas and matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to understand why the order of the labels behave like that in the following case.

I first plot the pandas dataframe and then I plot a horizontal line. I then change the legend labels and create them in the order (pandas column names, line label i.e. `['case0', 'case1', 'case2'] + ['line label']`). Why is the final result altered?

The only way to have the correct order is to use `ax.legend(['line label']+['case0', 'case1', 'case2'], fontsize=6, loc='upper left')` but this is counterintuitive.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

data = np.random.rand(5,3)

plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=120)
ax=pd.DataFrame(data).plot.bar(color=pal)
ax.axhline(y=0.4, lw=1, ls='--', c='k', label='line')
ax.legend(['case0', 'case1', 'case2'] + ['line label'], fontsize=6, loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some research and by default `lines`s are append to handles before graphs:

```
data = np.random.rand(5,3)


ax=pd.DataFrame(data).plot.bar()
ax.axhline(y=0.4, lw=1, ls='--', c='k', label='line')

#added some new graph for testing
pd.DataFrame(data).plot.area(ax=ax)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519547/2901002
handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
print (handles)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000000116E5E50>, 
  <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object at 0x00000000117420D0>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object at 0x0000000011742430>, 
  <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object at 0x0000000011732CD0>, 
  <BarContainer object of 5 artists>,
  <BarContainer object of 5 artists>,
  <BarContainer object of 5 artists>]
```

Possible solution is `append` handle to end of existing handles:

```
data = np.random.rand(5,3)

# plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=120)
ax=pd.DataFrame(data).plot.bar()


handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516413/add-axhline-to-legend#comment115315673_53519547
handles.append(ax.axhline(y=0.4, lw=1, ls='--', c='k', label='line'))
print (handles)
[<BarContainer object of 5 artists>,
 <BarContainer object of 5 artists>, 
 <BarContainer object of 5 artists>, 
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000011B39850>]
 
labels = ['case0', 'case1', 'case2'] + ['line label']
ax.legend(handles = handles, labels = labels)
```

Comment: Interesting and unexpected behavior. Thanks